# Adding subviews, yet I see nothing - iOS

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios, uinavigationbar, uilabel

I have a Controller of which I have a few subviews. At a certain point in the code, I remove them, and then later on, I add them. Here is the code I use to add them:

```
[self.view addSubview:dateLabel];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Right after these lines, I print out:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self.view subviews]);
```

and the output I get is:

```
"<UINavigationBar: 0x614a8f0; frame = (0 0; 320 48); layer = <CALayer: 0x6129ee0>>",
    "<UILabel: 0x614d500; frame = (0 48; 320 25); text = 'Dec. 15, 2010 - Jan. 15, ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x614d570>>",
    "<UITableView: 0x507ee00; frame = (0 73; 320 390); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x9f57930>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>"
```

However, the only thing I see on my screen is the navigation bar. Why is the label and the tableView not showing up even if it says here that it is a subView?

I have also tried to add the following code after adding the subviews:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:tableView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:dateLabel];
```

but it still does not work.

Comment: I think they are outside of the bounds of the containing view. What if you change the frames of the subviews?

Comment: .... could you edit your question and perhaps put up the code you are actually using to try to display the sub views as we can then troubleshoot and guide you from there onwards. There could be 100's of reasons why your view is not being displayed. An NSLog that states your view is there does not help to explain why it is not being displayed on the screen itself. thanks

Comment: changing the frames does not work either :(

Comment: I updated and posted the code I use to display the subviews.

Comment: Have you tried to change the z-order of your subviews?  There is a bringToFront method in UIView that does this.

Comment: yes, this does not work either :(

Comment: `-addSubview:` always puts the new view at the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your controller a UIViewController? Have you checked it has been presented correctly? For example with presentModalViewController:self ?